# How to add search domain to Vinagre Remote Access Viewer

Tags: remote-desktop, vinagre

I'm trying to connect to a pc of a friend which also uses **Ubuntu 14.04**. I'm using Vinagre Remote Desktop Viewer to connect to him using his **external IP** but the program don't find him because it is searching only inside my local network. When I went on the page to add new domain, there were no domain besides local...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxWav.png //screen to set up the domain

**notes**: He already set up the server on Desktop Sharing and also tried [this tutorial](http://bookofzeus.com/articles/linux/install-vnc-server-and-vnc-client-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first get your friend to go to [this](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) website to get his external ip, get them to send it to you... put the ip in manually and it should work... something like this:

[image]

Comment: according to this site you gave, his port for remote desktop access (5900) is closed but he already set it up on dconf-editor and also on Desktop Sharing Preferences

Comment: I didnt ask himm to worry about the port or if it said it was open, I just asked him to use it to get the external ip

Comment: @WeltenSchann ^

Comment: I have not used this program before, but yes I would guess that is correct

Comment: may I ask what you need it for? SSH may be a ton easier

Comment: didn't worked too

Comment: You opened the port?